# How do I set the body of a HttpPut on Android? (without adding libraries)

Tags: java, android

I want to upload some data from an Android application to Pachube.

[Update: For people reading this in 2013, "Pachube" became "Cosm", which is now "Xively".]

[This hurl](http://hurl.it/?url=http://api.pachube.com/v2/feeds/YOUR_FEED_ID.json&header-keys%5B%5D=X-PachubeApiKey&header-vals%5B%5D=YOUR_API_KEY_HERE&method=PUT&post-body=%7B%22title%22%3a%22Your%20Changed%20Title%22,%22version%22%3a%221.0.0%22,%22datastreams%22%3a%5B%7B%22id%22%3a%22stream0%22,%22current_value%22:12.3%7D,%7B%22id%22%3a%22stream1%22,%22current_value%22:24.2%7D%5D%7D) is provided by their [documentation](https://pachube.com/docs/v2/feed/update.html) as an example.

How can I achieve this with Android's implementation of HttpPut (or HttpPost)?

I don't really want to have to add any extra libraries, as I want to keep the application as small as possible.

I already have a JSONObject with my data in it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is some pseudocode. Note that you shouldn't send form url encoded data in a PUT request, as it may break server side OAuth (if being used):

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPut put = new HttpPut(url);
put.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
put.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
put.setEntity(new StringEntity(jsonObj.writeValue()));
HttpResponse response = client.execute(put);
```

Comment: This is how I've been trying to do it, annoyingly I just get "400 Bad Request" every time.

Comment: Are you including your API key? From the linked reference in your OP, it needs to be included, with a header name of 'X-PachubeApiKey'.

Comment: Thanks, it's working now - turns out I had to include "version":"1.0.0" in the JSON.

put.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
put.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");

Were not necessary, and jsonObj.writeValue() should be jsonObj.toString().

Comment: Is JSONObject's writeValue() method gone now? it's not working on my project.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this in Java / Android without any additional libraries is:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com/whatever");
HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
httpCon.setDoOutput(true);
httpCon.setRequestMethod("PUT");
OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(httpCon.getOutputStream());
out.write("Data you want to put"); // for example your JSON object
out.close();
```

UPDATE - as per comments:

you can get the response for example by calling `httpCon.getInputStream()` and/or `httpCon.getErrorStream()` etc.

Comment: How would I get the result from that?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I went for the other suggestion in the end as it matches how I do Get.